# Function stored in object property returns array instead of object

Tags: javascript, object, arrow-functions

I'm trying to set an object property using a function that returns and object.

The problem is when setting the property I'm getting back an array as a value instead of the object.

```js
const newUserRights = {
  A: { id: '1'},
  B: { id: '2'},
  C: { id: '3'},
  D: { id: '4'},
  E: { id: '5'},
  F: { id: '6'},
  G: { id: '7'},
};

var Post = {
  name: '',
  rs: function r(rights = []) {
    let r = {};
    for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(newUserRights)) {
      r[v.id] = false;
    }
    if (rights.length > 0) {
      for (ri of rights) {
        r[ri] = true;
      }
    }
    return r;
  },
};

// trying to set the property
Post.rs = ['1', '2'];
```

Desired output:

```js
Post: {
    name:'',
    rs:{
        1: true,
        2: true,
        3: false,
        4: false,
        5: false,
        6: false,
        7: false
    }
}
```

But getting:

```js
Post: {
    name:'',
    rs:['1', '2']
}
```

I want to know

- what I'm doing wrong
- How to return the Object
- Is this a good practice

Thank you

Comment: You're not calling the function, you're just replacing the property with the array.

Comment: _"But getting: ..."_ - Because you overwrite the content of the `.rs` property with the array `['1', '2']` here: `Post.rs = ['1', '2'];` -> `Post.rs(['1', '2'])`

Comment: doing this the console is logging the function and not the return value ! when trying somethins like `Post.rs(['1', '2'])()` i'm getting an error of `rs is not a function`

Comment: @Majd _"doing this the console is logging the function and not the return value"_ - No, it does not: https://jsfiddle.net/u2ztxchf/; _"Post.rs(['1', '2'])()"_ - Nobody said to execute the result (an object) of `.rs()` o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, but this keeps the solution close to your attempt.

I considered an implementation using `this`, but thought that would add unhelpful complexity.

I will note, however, that any time you have a series of incrementing integers, an `Array` should be considered because it has those keys implicitly.

```js
const newUserRights = {
  A: { id: '1'},
  B: { id: '2'},
  C: { id: '3'},
  D: { id: '4'},
  E: { id: '5'},
  F: { id: '6'},
  G: { id: '7'},
};

const applyRights = (o, rights = []) => {
  const rs = {};
  for (const [, { id }] of Object.entries(newUserRights)) {
    rs[id] = false;
  }
  
  for (const r of rights) {
    rs[r] = true;
  }
  
  o.rs = rs;
  return o;
};

const Post = { name: '' };
console.log(applyRights(Post, ['1', '2']));
```

Comment: Or... You know... Just execute `Post.rs(['1', '2'])` - which already does what OP wants. Without the need to refactor anything.

Comment: No. That would not work in the way OP wants, Andreas (as your own jsfiddle demonstrates, above).

Comment: Adding `name: ''` to the result should be quite easy... The main problem is still the way OP "calls" the function in `.rs`

Comment: Lots of ways to skin this cat!

Comment: I'm using this method to instante the object , so I need to pass the parameter and call the function to have a const object property as an object, in other examples where the function doesn't take params it's working, but this one is not

Comment: @BenAston ended up using your method which was the only working option, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for a [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) (and probably also a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) to read the value).

```js
const newUserRights = {
  A: { id: '1'},
  B: { id: '2'},
  C: { id: '3'},
  D: { id: '4'},
  E: { id: '5'},
  F: { id: '6'},
  G: { id: '7'},
};

var Post = (() => {
  let rs;

  return {
    name: '',
    get rs() { return rs },
    set rs(rights = []) {
      rs = {};
      for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(newUserRights)) {
        rs[v.id] = false;
      }
      if (rights.length > 0) {
        for (ri of rights) {
          rs[ri] = true;
        }
      }
    },
  };
})();

// trying to set the property
Post.rs = ['1', '2'];
console.log(Post);
```

I've used an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) here to limit the scope of the `rs` variable, so only the returned `Post` has access to it. Alternatively you could also omit the IIFE and store the value as an object property instead.

```js
var Post = {
  name: '',
  get rs() { return this._rs },
  set rs(rights = []) {
    this._rs = {};
    for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(newUserRights)) {
      this._rs[v.id] = false;
    }
    if (rights.length > 0) {
      for (ri of rights) {
        this._rs[ri] = true;
      }
    }
  },
};
```

This does however result in `Post` having 3 properties instead of 2. `name`, `rs` holding the getter/setter, and `_rs` to store the actual value.

Another thing I want to point out is that `if (rights.length > 0)` is unnecessary. Looping with `for (ri of rights)` over an empty list will execute the for-block content for each element in the list, but since the list is empty nothing is executed.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1:

You just need to call the function proper way `Post.rs(['1', '2'])`

```
const newUserRights = {
      A: { id: '1'},
      B: { id: '2'},
      C: { id: '3'},
      D: { id: '4'},
      E: { id: '5'},
      F: { id: '6'},
      G: { id: '7'},
    };
    
    var Post = {
      name: '',
      rs: function (rights = []) {
        let r = {};
        for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(newUserRights)) {
          r[v.id] = false;
        }
        if (rights.length > 0) {
          for (ri of rights) {
            r[ri] = true;
          }
        }
        return r;
      },
    };
    
    // trying to set the property
    
    console.log(Post.rs(['1', '2']));
```

### Solution 2:

Little bit cleaner way:

```
const newUserRights = {
  A: { id: '1'},
  B: { id: '2'},
  C: { id: '3'},
  D: { id: '4'},
  E: { id: '5'},
  F: { id: '6'},
  G: { id: '7'},
};

var Post = {
  name: '',
  rs: function (rights = []) {
  const refDict = rights.reduce((obj, value) => {
  return {...obj, [value]: value};
  }, {});
  
  const userRights = {};
  
  for (const [, { id }] of Object.entries(newUserRights)) {
   userRights[id] = id in refDict && true; 
  }
  return userRights;
  },
};

// trying to set the property

console.log(Post.rs(['1', '2']));
```